# Give title to multiple charts with the text in the merged cells in row 1

Tags: excel, vba, charts, title

http://bit.ly/1CG7T4c this link shows the sample data and the charts I am obtaining by running the code given below. I have dynamic number of departments.

I want each chart to take the titles as the respective department names i.e. those given in each of the merged cells above the data for each chart.

Kindly suggest me a code for the same.

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub PlotSeparateChartsByMergedFirstRow()
 Dim rUsed As Range, rMerged As Range, rChtData As Range
 Dim rChtDat1 As Range, rChtDat2 As Range
 Dim iColMerge As Long, iColData As Long
 Dim cht1 As Chart, cht2 As Chart

 Const iChtHeight As Double = 175

 Set rUsed = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 iColMerge = 1

 Do
 iColMerge = iColMerge + 1
 If iColMerge > rUsed.Columns.Count Then Exit Do

 If rUsed.Cells(1, iColMerge).MergeCells Then
 Set rMerged = rUsed.Cells(1, iColMerge).MergeArea
 Set rChtData = rMerged.Resize(rUsed.Rows.Count)

 ' x values
 Set rChtDat1 = rUsed.Columns(1)
 Set rChtDat2 = rUsed.Columns(1)

 ' y values
 For iColData = 1 To rChtData.Columns.Count - 1 Step 2
 Set rChtDat1 = Union(rChtDat1, rChtData.Columns(iColData))
 Set rChtDat2 = Union(rChtDat2, rChtData.Columns(iColData + 1))
 Next

 ' charts
 ' 2007, 2010
 Set cht1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, rChtData.Left,        rChtData.Height, rChtData.Width, iChtHeight).Chart

 With cht1
 .SetSourceData rChtDat1, xlColumns
 End With

 ' 2007, 2010
 Set cht2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, rChtData.Left, rChtData.Height + iChtHeight, rChtData.Width, iChtHeight).Chart

 With cht2
 .SetSourceData rChtDat2, xlColumns
 End With

 nd If
 iColMerge = iColMerge + rMerged.Columns.Count - 1
 Loop

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the chart has a title, then link the title to the first cell of the merged block in the first row.

```
With cht1
    .SetSourceData rChtDat1, xlColumns
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "=" & rUsed.Cells(1, iColMerge).Address(, , , True)
End With
```

Comment: Great. Mark it as an answer.